# One click closure windows tool to compile all js files in folder

Tags: javascript, windows, minify, google-closure-compiler

Is there a tool or a bat file or some such that allows one click to compile all js files inside a folder into one compiled js file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google's Page Speed tool has a Closure Compiler integration that will automatically compile your site's Javascript for you.  You can find more information on Page Speed and its Closure integration here:

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/download.html

Comment: On that website, I see a couple of browser plugins, an Apache module, and an SDK. Am I missing something? I'm also looking for a tool to compile all `js` files in a folder on Windows.

Comment: After a quick glance, it seems the PageSpeed-Closure integration is now offered in the form of the [PageSpeed Service](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service).

Comment: I ended up making a custom build scrip in js to be ran by Window's WScript/CScript. I still wish they offered something nice and configurable for js developers.

Comment: It's important to notice that this minifies every individual file into as many individual minified files - whereas Closure Compiler's big advantage is that it minifies only the bits you need from many files into one single concat/minified file. Using this approach isn't really a one-click solution to the OP's question - it does something less useful (albeit more conveniently).