# Reload all commonJS modules in DEV mode when using Closure Compiler

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, google-closure-compiler

Play Framework 2.2 enables me to use the Google Closure Compiler and thus using a more modular structure for my client side code.

To enable commonJs module functionality, I appended the following to my `build.sbt`:

`closureCompilerOptions += "commonJs"`

The compilation itself is fine and works as expected-but when I make changes to the code that is burried in `assets/javascript/module3/index.js` and required in `assets/javascripts/main.js`, the closure compiler only refreshes the compiled result when I make a change to `main.js`. This is a somehow expected behavior, but I wonder if there was a closure compiler flag to **always** compile the file on every request in DEV mode?

As you can imagine, this gets frustrating very quickly so I think there must be such flag burried somewhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [One click closure windows tool to compile all js files in folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772889/one-click-closure-windows-tool-to-compile-all-js-files-in-folder)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.